# How to find the start date and end date of a particular task in dag in airflow?

Tags: airflow

I'm using kwargs['execution_date'] for getting the execution date of dag but it gives the time when the overall dag is invoked, but i need the time where a particular task is started and ended in airflow.

Answer (score 0):

- Use [`get_task_instance()`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/api/common/experimental/get_task_instance.py#L26) utility function to obtain a [`TaskInstance`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/taskinstance.py#L134)
- From `TaskInstance` object, you can get [`start_date` & `end_date`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/taskinstance.py#L153)

---

As a sidenote, the `context` / `kwargs` [do contain](https://bcb.github.io/airflow/execute-context) `end_date` & `END_DATE` (nodash-format), but not `start_date`

Comment: I'm getting that 'end_date' in dd-mm-yyyy format...but i need in dd-mm-yyyy hh-mm-ss format.How can i get 'end_date' in that format.

Answer (score 0):

```
from airflow.api.common.experimental import get_task_instance

execution_date = context['execution_date'] - timedelta(0)
task_instance = get_task_instance.get_task_instance(<dag_id>,<task_id>,execution_date)
start_date = task_instance.start_date
end_date = task_instance.end_date
```

Comment: Can you please add some comments to your code? Explain why/how this code solves the problem!